# Cocossharp support for Xamarin.Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, monogame, cocossharp

I am looking to develop a game using cocossharp targeting Mac. When I am trying to add NuGet packages, CocosSharp packages are failing to add with the following error:

> Could not install package 'CocosSharp 1.7.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   'Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Could someone explain which is the right package or if there was a versioning problem that I am hitting into here.

I also noticed the - http://mono.github.io/CocosSharp/ where I see an issue "#371 CCGameView: Add Mac support" marked to be part of the next release. Does that mean, Cocossharp is currently not supported on Mac?